# Scope of This JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, scope, dom-events

I have a question and an issue wrt the code below:

My question is what is the scope of the variable `loaded` here. The reason why I ask this is the `onload="if(loaded==1)inittextarea()` code is working fine on Firefox and not IE8. Why is this happening? Is there something specific I need to do here? Or is it not a valid practice?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/default.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var loaded = 0; /*Point of interest*/
    function jsLoaded() {
    loaded =1; 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function inittextarea() {
        alert("test")
        tinyMCE.init({  
            elements : "content",
            theme : "advanced",
            readonly : true,
            mode : "exact",
            theme : "advanced",
            readonly : true,
            setup : function(ed) {
                ed.onInit.add(function() {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceToggleVisualAid");
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" onload="jsLoaded()" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="if(loaded==1)inittextarea()"><!--Works on Firefox only-->
    *Usual stuff*
</body></html>
```

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload` on `<script>` elements isn't generally supported. You could work around this by simply putting a `<script>` element below the TinyMCE `<script>` element:

```
<script src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jsLoaded();
</script>
```

Although actually this is all unnecessary: by the time `<body>`'s `onload` fires, all the JavaScript will be guaranteed to have loaded, so there's no need for the check:

```
<body onload="inittextarea()">
```

Comment: Best answer. Why use `jsLoaded` when you're already handling the `load` event?

Answer (score 2):

The use of onload in the body tag is frowned upon now as best practice. Perhaps you should revise they way your initialisation happens.

This [article](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html)  explains.

Comment: Actually, using the `onload` attribute of the `<body>` element is the only standardised way of capturing the fact that the document has loaded so could be seen as best practice.

Comment: @tarskythehutch @Tim As of now i have a few limitations in using the approach mentioned in http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html . So, is there a way i could mod something in the current approach to make this work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Script onLoad doesn't work in IE.

Comment: What do you think is the alternative for this? Any workarounds?

Comment: I always use JQuery. Then I initialize TinyMCE in the document.load. Works well and you get a lot extra with the library that will be useful! And you don't need to worry about individual browser differences as much. Everyones a winner! ;-)